# How do I stop my servo from repeating the loop and perform the rest of the functions?

Tags: arduino-uno

The project has a makeshift meter (via a half circle cutout and a servo motor operated lever). On program start (button 2), the lever will move to the left hand side at the 9 o'clock position. Once in place, after a short delay, the program will accept input from the button 1 and keep a count while moving the lever toward the 3 o’clock position stopping at at 10-2 w 2 sec delay. When it reaches the position, it stops the count and remembers it.

Repeat same thing but with buttons 4 and 5 respectively. Really important that the count is saved for both buttons 1 and 5.

Pressing button 3 will measure the inputs of button 5 and display them on the meter as a ratio of button 5 presses over button 1 + button 5 presses. If it leans right, that means you had more presses in the first stage than second (for ease of understanding I’ll probably have instructions that say to start with right hand so that leaning right means right hand dominance and left is left handed). Below is a picture of my set up.

*I numbered the buttons 1-5 left to right not by the pin number.

The problem I have is that after button 2 or 4 get pushed the servo just keeps moving to the seven positions I have set as a timer over and over.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int button1 = 2;   // button 1 pin/left hand main pin
const int button2 = 3;   // button 2 pin/left start pin 
const int button3 = 4;   // button 3 pin/right hand main pin
const int button4 = 5;   // button 4 pin/right start pin
const int button5 = 6;   // button 5 pin/results pin
const int servoPin = 9;  // servo motor pin

int count1 = 0;          // counter for button 1
int count2 = 0;          // counter for button 5

Servo servo;             // servo motor object

void setup() {
  // set button pins as inputs
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT);
  pinMode(button5, INPUT);

  servo.attach(servoPin); // attach servo motor to pin
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button2) == HIGH) {  // if button 2 is pressed
    // move servo motor to 9 o'clock position
    servo.write(180);
    delay(500);  // wait for servo to reach position

    // start accepting input from button 1
    while (digitalRead(button1) == LOW) {
      count1++;  // increment counter
      // move servo motor to 3 o'clock position
      servo.write(180);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(150);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(120);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(90);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(60);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(30);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(0);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      
    }

    // repeat the same process for button 4
    while (digitalRead(button4) == LOW) {
      count2++;  // increment counter
      // move servo motor to 3 o'clock position
      servo.write(180);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(150);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(120);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(90);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(60);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(30);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
      servo.write(0);
      delay(2000);  // wait for servo to reach position
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(button3) == LOW) {  // if button 3 is pressed
    // calculate ratio of button 4 presses to total button presses
    float ratio = (float)count2 / (count1 + count2);

    // Display ratio on meter
    servo.write(90 + (int)(ratio * 90));
  }
}
```

[image: Arduino set up]

Comment: `keep a count while moving the lever toward the 3 o’clock` ... your code does not do any counting while the servo is moving

Comment: Could you explain please?

Comment: your code is `move servo, pause, move servo, pause, etc.etc` there is no other code while the servo is moving

Comment: You might want to learn about [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and experiment with them. This approach will most probably be the appropriate one.

Comment: You won't correctly count the button presses unless you do some sort of [debouncing](https://learn.adafruit.com/make-it-switch/debouncing). There are libraries that can handle that for you. Also, as pointed out by the busybee, you will have to learn about finite state machines. I recommend this [tutorial by Majenko](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine).

Answer (score 0):

You have pulldown resistors on all your buttons, so all of your input pins are LOW when nobody is touching the buttons. When you press a button, the input goes HIGH. In your code, when you do

```
  if (digitalRead(button2) == HIGH) {  // if button 2 is pressed
```

it enters the if block, if the button is pressed, because the button2 input is high when the button is pressed. Then you move the servo to position 180 and wait a bit. The next line

```
    while (digitalRead(button1) == LOW) {
```

enters the while loop if the input pin is low. The input pin is that, when the button is NOT pressed, because of the pulldown resistor and that is why the servo starts moving when button2 is pressed, unless button1 is also pressed when you press button2. To stop that, change the LOW to HIGH in the while loop condition. Then it will only enter the while loop when the button is pressed and skip it if it is not pressed..

As suggested by the busybee, you might benefit from studying state machines.

Comment: Same problem in   

    while (digitalRead(button4) == LOW) {

and

    if (digitalRead(button3) == LOW) {  // if button 3 is pressed